# How to act on a http.post.subscribe(...) inside method implementation and calling

Tags: angular

I am having a hard time understanding their async/await behavior. I understand that I can't simply await calls as I am used to in dotnet. I have the following simple method which tries to log in on some rest API:

```
  login(email:string, password:string ){

    let httpOptions:Object = {

      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }),
      responseType: 'text'
    };

    const user: User = { UserName: email, Password: password };
    return this.http.post<User>(`${this.projectsUrl}/login`, user, httpOptions).subscribe(
      (response : any) => {
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', response);
      }
    );
  }
```

I am calling the `login` method from my `LoginComponent`

```
  login() {
    if (this.emailFormControl.value != "" && this.passwordFormControl.value != "") {
      this.authService.login(this.emailFormControl.value!, this.passwordFormControl.value!);
      // I want to get the result of the login method, NOT some subscription
    }
  }
```

I am finding all kinds of examples of deprecated solutions like `.toPromise`, `.map`, and `.do`. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Turn it into a promise that you _can_ await, or subscribe to it. The tutorial introduces dealing with observables: https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt4#observable-data. You can also read up on RxJS: https://rxjs.dev/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way after the suggestion of jonrsharpe.

```
  async login(email:string, password:string ){

    let httpOptions:Object = {

      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }),
      responseType: 'text'
    };

    const user: User = { UserName: email, Password: password };
    const result$ = this.http.post<any>(`${this.projectsUrl}/login`, user, httpOptions);
    let token = await lastValueFrom(result$);

    if (token != "") {
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
      this.messageService.add(`auth serv: token ${token}`);
      this.loggedIn = true;
    }

    return this.loggedIn;
  }
```

if there is a better way of doing this I'd be happy to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

You return the subscription. Return the observable:

```
...
return this.http.post<User>(`${this.projectsUrl}/login`, user, httpOptions).pipe(
  tap((response) => localStorage.setItem('id_token', response)),
);
...
```

And subscribe in the component:

```
...
this.authService.login(...).subscribe(console.log);
...
```